# Replace a random instance of a substring in a string

Tags: python

Say I have the string

```
s = 'x x x x x'
```

I want to randomly change one of the 'x' to y

```
s2 = 'x x y x x'
```

x and y will be multiple characters long.

If I just wanted to change the first instance of x, I would use string.replace, but how can I change a random instance?

Comment: Is this only for cases of strings with a sequence of one character type separated by spaces?

Comment: Are the tokens (`xx`, `yy`, ...) always separated by exactly one space?

Comment: They are not cleanly separated, it could be arbitrary characters eg sentences, with x and y being multiple words.

Comment: Then please give an example of the strings you're *actually* dealing with.

Comment: Are the random substrings of fixed lengths or variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `re.finditer` to retrieve the start/end of all possible matches and do an appropriate replacement. This will cover variable length replacing, but does mean you need to be wary of re syntax for the `frm` argument.

```
import re
from random import choice

def replace_random(src, frm, to):
    matches = list(re.finditer(frm, src))
    replace = choice(matches)
    return src[:replace.start()] + to + src[replace.end():]
```

Example:

```
>>> [replace_random('x x x x x', r'\bx\b', 'y') for _ in range(10)]
['y x x x x', 'x x x x y', 'x x y x x', 'x y x x x', 'x x x y x', 'x x x y x', 'x x y x x', 'x y x x x', 'x x x x y', 'x x y x x']
```

Comment: You could always `re.escape` `frm`if you want it to behave like a `str.replace`.

Comment: @mgilson Yep... for production purposes it should probably be documented that it's expected an actual regex pattern be supplied... unless the OP prefers adding another option which enables the function to behave in two modes... but that's probably just confusing...

Comment: I think if you would use `needle`, `haystack` and `replacement` as variable names it could also make the example a bit more clear - but maybe that's just my personal preference.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you. On the last line, it should be src, not s though.

Comment: @user2953349 errr yes... not sure how I copied/pasted that wrongly, but corrected :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
import random

def replace_random(string, str_a, str_b):
    rand = max(random.randint(0, string.count(str_a)), 1)
    return string.replace(str_a, str_b, rand).replace(str_b, str_a, rand - 1)

print replace_random('x x x x x', 'x', 'y')
```